# Classic ASP: Trouble with displaying Query Results with HTML Table

Tags: html, asp-classic

I have a problem displaying query results in an HTML form. When I process this code, it displays blank cells in my HTML table. Any tips or advice would be appreciated.

ASP:

```
<%
dim query, myDSN, Connect, rs

myDSN = "PROVIDER=MICROSOFT.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;DATA SOURCE=" & Server.Mappath("/MasterDB.accdb")

query = "SELECT * FROM DAY_DATA;"

Set Connect = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Connect.Open myDSN
Set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")
rs.Open query, Connect
%>
```

Result page HTML:

```
<table border="1" width="100%">
<tr>
<%for each x in rs.Fields
    response.write("<th>" & x.name & "</th>")
next%>
</tr>
<%do until rs.EOF%>
    <tr>
    <%for each x in rs.Fields%>
       <td><%Response.Write(x.value)%></td>
    <%next
    rs.MoveNext%>
    </tr>
<%loop
rs.close
conn.close
%>
</table>
```

If I can get this to work, I will replace the query string with one that is generated with their input. Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created this function to do just that task... hope this helps:

```
Sub WriteRS(ByRef myRS)
    Dim i, fCount
    Response.Write ("<br><br clear=""all""><table cellspacing=1 cellpadding=5 border=1><tr>")
    For i = 0 To myRS.Fields.Count - 1
        Response.Write ("<td nowrap>" & myRS.Fields(i).name & "</td>" & vbNewLine)
    Next
    Response.Write ("</tr>" & vbNewLine)
    If Not myRS.BOF THEN myRS.MoveFirst
    fCount = myRS.Fields.Count
    Do Until myRS.EOF
        Response.Write ("<tr>" & vbNewLine)
        For i = 0 To fCount - 1
            Response.Write ("<td nowrap>" & CheckValue(Trim(myRS.Fields.Item(i).Value), "&nbsp;") & "</td>" & vbNewLine)
        Next
        Response.Write ("</tr>" & vbNewLine)
        Response.Flush
        myRS.MoveNext
    Loop
    If Not myRS.BOF THEN
        myRS.MoveFirst
    Else
        Response.Write ("<tr><td colspan=""" & fCount & """>No Data Found</td</tr>" & vbNewLine)
    End If
    Response.Write ("</table><br clear=""all"">")
End Sub
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Glad it helped! Please do mark this is the answer if it did answer your question, so we don't have people dropping in trying to fix it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `x.value` with `rs(x.name)`.

```
<%do until rs.EOF%>
    <tr>
    <%for each x in rs.Fields%>
    <td><%=rs(x.Name)%></td>
    <%next
    rs.MoveNext%>
    </tr>
<%loop%>
```

If `x.Name` isn't returning anything, either (i.e. you don't see the column names in your table), try fiddling with the cursor type and lock type.

```
rs.Open query, Connect, 1, 2
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work. Thanks for the tip though!

Comment: @Diogenes: are you sure it's the display code that's not working? I.e. are you sure you're connecting to the database correctly? Add the `, 1, 2` to the end of the `rs.Open` line, and then do a `Response.Write rs.RecordCount`.

Comment: I've linked the page to the adovbs.inc file so that shouldn't be an issue.